# Android UI testing: how to click to Android dialog?

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

**Problem:**
I cannot run test, because when Activity using fullscreen mode, Android dialog (see picture) is showed.

**Goal:**
I want to click to `GOT IT` and close the dialog.

**Code (Kotlin):**

```
//device is instance of UiDevice UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())

val gotIt = device.findObject(UiSelector()
        //.clickable(true)
        //.checkable(false)
        //.className("android.widget.Button")
        //.packageName("com.android.launcher3")
        //.resourceId("android:id/ok")
        //.index(3) //by index for language-independent
          .text("GOT IT")
)
if (gotIt.waitForExists(3000)) {
    try {
        return gotIt.click()
    } catch (e: UiObjectNotFoundException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
} else Log.i(TAG, "clickViewingFullscreenDialog: btn not exists")
```

I tried many combination of selectors, but i **still cannot click** to `GOT IT`. Selectors are correct, but dialog is as "invisible" or unfocusable. Cannot click to dialog.

**Additional info:**
Trying on Emulator Nexus 5 Android 7.0.
I tried `uiautomatorviewer` and `layoutinspector` to get information about `View hierarchy` to find this Android `Dialog`, but i can get information only about `android home screen` (see second picture), not about own `Activity` (first picture).

[image: Android dialog]
[image: Home screen dialog]

Comment: Your snippet worked for me for a permission dialog, to tap the Allow button.

Answer (score 1):

is "GOT IT" a positive or neutral button?
if it's positive, click on ID `android.R.id.button2.`
And in case it's neutral button, click on ID `android.R.id.button3`